# How do I use Emgu CV's Surf library to match to a library of images

Tags: emgucv, surf

Emgu CV's Example set has an example on how to use SURFDetector to detect features from a feature and then use Features2DTracker's MatchFeature call (which seems to use KNN) to match a "model" image to an "observed" image. This part makes sense.

Now, if I wanted to build a library of images, each using image's SURF features to find the best match for a given image, what are my options? Instead of doing a brute force match with each image in my library, can I build a tree? I'm confused because Emgu seems to be building some sort of tree, but only between two images:

```
     //Create a SURF Tracker using k-d Tree
     SURFTracker tracker = new SURFTracker(modelFeatures);
```

I've read almost every thread on the site on the subject but can't understand how to get started. I also though about using histogram matching -- splitting each RGB channel into bins and comparing the normalized count. Instead of calculating the euclidean distance to each image in the library, if I wanted to partition my search space based on RGB count, that would still mean branching on one of R,G,B -- and I'm not sure how to build that decision tree.

I only started reading about this topic a few days ago, so apologies for my naivety.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a lookat EMGU CV's TrafficSignRecognition. It is the same as the SURFFeature example, but applied in real life. It is able to detect whether the given image matches with the image given and how many there are. I tried it. You can take a look at it.

Comment: I looked over the code and this seems to identify all the places in the given image that match a particular stop sign. It doesn't search a set of images to find the best match.

Answer (score 1):

SURFTracker seems to use the FLANN (Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors) library that comes with OpenCV (so has Emgu bindings, too) while it:

- builds a tree from the descriptors extracted from the template image (so that it's faster to match the points of the sample to those of the template). So the tree is built for one image only (the template).
- when given a sample, it extracts the descriptors, calculates a match (a pairing between the template and the image descriptors), taking into account the spatial consistency of the matching points, too (right side to right side, left side to left side)

Supposing you'd like to be faster than simply doing the above procedure for every image, you would have to build *one* tree out of every descriptor for every image, and put that into a FLANN Index while keeping track of which descriptor came from which image (probably in a separate array).

When given an image, you could extract all the descriptors from it, and match them one by one to the FLANN tree (this is faster than doing it with a different tree for every template descriptor collection). So for every descriptor X in the sample, you get a most similar descriptor Y that comes from image Z. These can be used as votes for similar images (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model).

However, this method doesn't take into account the spatial consistency of the points... but it's possible to check that, too, for the top k images we have votes for (k << N, the number of all images in the system).

Answer (score 1):

This code makes a Matrix of each image, appends them all together, then gets makes a FLANN Index, does an KNN search on it, and then returns the matches. All the code is here:

```
/// <summary>
/// Main method.
/// </summary>
public IList<IndecesMapping> Match()
{
    string[] dbImages = {"1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"};
    string queryImage = "query.jpg";

    IList<IndecesMapping> imap;

    // compute descriptors for each image
    var dbDescsList = ComputeMultipleDescriptors(dbImages, out imap);

    // concatenate all DB images descriptors into single Matrix
    Matrix<float> dbDescs = ConcatDescriptors(dbDescsList);

    // compute descriptors for the query image
    Matrix<float> queryDescriptors = ComputeSingleDescriptors(queryImage);

    FindMatches(dbDescs, queryDescriptors, ref imap);

    return imap;
}

/// <summary>
/// Computes image descriptors.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">Image filename.</param>
/// <returns>The descriptors for the given image.</returns>
public Matrix<float> ComputeSingleDescriptors(string fileName)
{
    Matrix<float> descs;

    using (Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(fileName))
    {
        VectorOfKeyPoint keyPoints = detector.DetectKeyPointsRaw(img, null);
        descs = detector.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(img, null, keyPoints);
    }

    return descs;
}

/// <summary>
/// Convenience method for computing descriptors for multiple images.
/// On return imap is filled with structures specifying which descriptor ranges in the concatenated matrix belong to what image. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileNames">Filenames of images to process.</param>
/// <param name="imap">List of IndecesMapping to hold descriptor ranges for each image.</param>
/// <returns>List of descriptors for the given images.</returns>
public IList<Matrix<float>> ComputeMultipleDescriptors(string[] fileNames, out IList<IndecesMapping> imap)
{
    imap = new List<IndecesMapping>();

    IList<Matrix<float>> descs = new List<Matrix<float>>();

    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
    {
        var desc = ComputeSingleDescriptors(fileNames[i]);
        descs.Add(desc);

        imap.Add(new IndecesMapping()
        {
            fileName = fileNames[i],
            IndexStart = r,
            IndexEnd = r + desc.Rows - 1
        });

        r += desc.Rows;
    }

    return descs;
}

/// <summary>
/// Computes 'similarity' value (IndecesMapping.Similarity) for each image in the collection against our query image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dbDescriptors">Query image descriptor.</param>
/// <param name="queryDescriptors">Consolidated db images descriptors.</param>
/// <param name="images">List of IndecesMapping to hold the 'similarity' value for each image in the collection.</param>
public void FindMatches(Matrix<float> dbDescriptors, Matrix<float> queryDescriptors, ref IList<IndecesMapping> imap)
{
    var indices = new Matrix<int>(queryDescriptors.Rows, 2); // matrix that will contain indices of the 2-nearest neighbors found
    var dists = new Matrix<float>(queryDescriptors.Rows, 2); // matrix that will contain distances to the 2-nearest neighbors found

    // create FLANN index with 4 kd-trees and perform KNN search over it look for 2 nearest neighbours
    var flannIndex = new Index(dbDescriptors, 4);
    flannIndex.KnnSearch(queryDescriptors, indices, dists, 2, 24);

    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Rows; i++)
    {
        // filter out all inadequate pairs based on distance between pairs
        if (dists.Data[i, 0] < (0.6 * dists.Data[i, 1]))
        {
            // find image from the db to which current descriptor range belongs and increment similarity value.
            // in the actual implementation this should be done differently as it's not very efficient for large image collections.
            foreach (var img in imap)
            {
                if (img.IndexStart <= i && img.IndexEnd >= i)
                {
                    img.Similarity++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Concatenates descriptors from different sources (images) into single matrix.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="descriptors">Descriptors to concatenate.</param>
/// <returns>Concatenated matrix.</returns>
public Matrix<float> ConcatDescriptors(IList<Matrix<float>> descriptors)
{
    int cols = descriptors[0].Cols;
    int rows = descriptors.Sum(a => a.Rows);

    float[,] concatedDescs = new float[rows, cols];

    int offset = 0;

    foreach (var descriptor in descriptors)
    {
        // append new descriptors
        Buffer.BlockCopy(descriptor.ManagedArray, 0, concatedDescs, offset, sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length);
        offset += sizeof(float) * descriptor.ManagedArray.Length;
    }

    return new Matrix<float>(concatedDescs);
}

public class IndecesMapping
{
  public int IndexStart { get; set; }
  public int IndexEnd { get; set; }
  public int Similarity { get; set; }
  public string fileName { get; set; }
}

private const double surfHessianThresh = 300;
private const bool surfExtendedFlag = true;
private SURFDetector detector = new SURFDetector(surfHessianThresh, surfExtendedFlag);
```